# Data parsing returning a bunch of urls

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I'm trying to get data using an AsyncLoader. The result I'm getting is only a bunch of links instead of having names of books. This is my code and this is the result. [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHD3b.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>> {

private static final int LOADER_ID=10;
public ArrayAdapter<Book> mAdapter;
private static final String DATA_API_REQUEST="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=10";
private ListView LV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID,null,  MainActivity.this);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    return new BookLoader(this,DATA_API_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<List<Book>> loader, List<Book> data) {
    LV=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    mAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<Book>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    LV.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(data);}
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
    mAdapter.clear();
}
```

Update :

Use

> variable.tostring

to the variable that you are setting TextView to. Here you are setting the object directly which the textview cannot convert so instead you can convert the object to String

Comment: Hi, overwrite the `toString()` method of your `Book` class

Comment: What is your `Book` class?

Comment: Show your Book class and note the elements you want from the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually printing a whole object try using the element you want to print for instance Book.name.toString() and then set it in the textview you are using in the adapter. furthurmore do paste the adapter code as well to let community understand the issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

as i mentioned in the comment, you need to overwrite the `toString()` method of your `Book` class.

Something like this in your `Book` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return this.bookName;
}
```

The output of the default toString method of most objects consists of the class name of the object as well as the object's hashcode, which is usually not what was intended. ([From here](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1608214))